# Testing the reliability of RS485

Tags: noise, digital-communications, rs485, crc

I have implemented an RS485 communication with CRC data validation and some algorithms to manage errors when the data received is lossy.

How can I test the packet loss during RS485 communication? Is there a way to make sufficient noise during the transmission stream?

Comment: Why would it lose packets? How does the algorithm determine the loss?

Comment: By crc algorithm

Comment: Why do you think you're going to have bit errors on your link?

Comment: So you created a system that sends RS485 packets.  What are you plugging into the other end of the cable?

Comment: To test the error detection feature that CRC provides, just send data packets with the CRC deliberately corrupted, or flip some of the bits that are sent after the CRC is calculated.  You should be able to simulate/model this behavior.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to see if things are working. Answer: (capacitive) couple the data line to a pulse generator / oscillator / AC / etc. Synchronize (trigger) that (generator) to the data stream, if needed. Adjust the frequency / duty /amplitude.

Comment: no matter what you program, the program can only correctly handle a finite quantity of scenarios.  figure out what would cause your algorithm to fail, the likelihood during normal operation, and the consequences of that failure.  crc, checksum, parity they can all potentially fail to catch errors.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to test that your packet loss algorithm detects errors, would be to simply plug the cable in and out while your device is receiving data.  You can make a counter in your software that increments for each bad packet received.  Check the counter to see how many errors you got.

If you want to find a general bit-error-rate you would need to connect the device in a way similar to its intended application.  Then send known byte-patterns or messages to the device.  Count how many bytes you received, and count how many bits in each byte were wrong.  Run that setup for a long time, so that you have millions or billions of samples.  The error rate is the ratio of the number of wrong bits to the total number of bits.

Answer (score 0):

> *How can I test the packet loss during RS485 communication? Is there a
> way to make sufficient noise during the transmission stream?*

Just before your transmit data feeds the RS485 output driver, exclusive-OR that data with a low duty cycle pulse that is capable of causing 1 or 2 consecutive bits of the packet transmission to become inverted (hence corrupted). This should always cause a receive error of some kind.

Count the received packets in error over a period of time and you'll start to get a feel for the extra security offered by adding the CRC algorithm.

You can also increase either the duty cycle of the corrupting pulse or, increase its repetition rate to produce extremes that may cause the CRC algorithm to be fooled into thinking the received data is good.

You might also choose to do dual receiver comparisons. You don't need to use the CRC supplied in the transmission - you could choose to ignore that and get a total number of all packets received (whether in error or not). Stats, stats and more stats!!